# ASP.NET HyperLink instead of LinkButton - how to avoid border around image?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-4.0, hyperlink, webforms-routing

I have an ASP.NET web site which contains some `ImageButton` controls that cause postbacks used to filter a list of products to certain groups of products.

The ImageButton was created something like this:

```
ImageButton _myImageButton = new ImageButton();
_myImageButton.ImageUrl = PicturePath + PictureName;
_myImageButton.Attributes.Add("border", "0");
_myImageButton.OnClick += handleImageButtonClick();
Controls.Add(_myImageButton);
```

Now I am moving to ASP.NET 4.0 with SEO-friendly paths like `/products/category/item`, and I'm using routing with Webforms to map URL's to webforms. In the process, I want to replace my image buttons with hyperlink controls showing the image, so that I can associate a navigational URL with each image.

I'm creating my new image hyperlink something like this:

```
HyperLink _myImageLink = new HyperLink();
_myImageLink.ImageUrl = PicturePath + PictureName;
_myImageLink.NavigateUrl = "/products/category/" + itemName;
_myImageLink.Attributes.Add("border", "0");
Controls.Add(_myImageLink);
```

The big problem I'm facing: the `ImageButton` used to put a `border="0"` attribute on the `<img>` tag in HTML to avoid a border around the image. But how can I achieve the same result using the hyper link control??

With the current setup, the `border="0"` gets stuck onto the `<a href="....">` tag - and that's not exactly what I want / need.

Any ideas?? Thoughts?? I already tried the `.BorderStyle` and `.BorderWidth` elements of the `HyperLink` class - doesn't seem to work for me (I still see a border around my image).

What am I missing?? How can I achieve my goal??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That attribute is not automatically inserted in ASP.NET 4.0 because it's deprecated; you should use CSS instead to set the `img` tag in question not to have a border. One possible suggestion would be to set it on `img` tags within `a` tags:

```
a img{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: That should be done in a <style> tag or in a style sheet, and you'll also want to make sure you don't have any CSS rules which would override that and cause a border. Finally, I sometimes find that I need to define a lack of a border instead with something like border: transparent 0; and I've never taken the time to figure out why. heh

Comment: OK, this did the trick (after a "good" refresh :-) - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you dont know the reason of the border.

this is just from the URL `<a>`

a simple css could fix that:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

or you could just set `text-decoration: none;` in your style of your `imageLink`

```
myImageLink.Attributes.Add("style", "text-decoration: none");
```

Comment: Tried that - and the attributes shows up in the HTML - but that doesn't solve the problem - the image still has a border around it.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the `ImageUrl` property of the hyperlink, why don't you add the image as a child of the hyperlink, that way you can still set all the properties you want on it.